# unsupported operand type(s) error

Tags: python-2.7

```
a = 3,3 b = 5,3
a2 = a**2
b2 = b**2
eq1_sum = a2 + 2ab + b2
eq2_sum = a2 - 2ab + b2
eq1_pow = (a + b)**2
eq2_pow = (a - b)**2
print ’First equation: %g = %g’, % (eq1_sum, eq1_pow)
print ’Second equation: %h = %h’, % (eq2_pow, eq2_pow)
```

This program it shows error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.` if you wish to use a floating-point number:

```
a = 3.3
b = 5.3
a2 = a**2
b2 = b**2
```

Otherwise, using a comma, you're creating a tuple:

```
>>> a = 3,3
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> a = 3.3
>>> type(a)
<type 'float'>
```

You're now getting an error because `a` and `b` are tuples and you can't raise tuples to a power.